# jQuery toggle menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a menu navigation that has parent horizontal bar as static 
and a vertical accordion child menu that interacts with the parent.

I have them working fine except one part where I want to toggle `show()` and `hide()` child menu when clicked on the same parent menu item.

I've looked at `toggle()` jQuery API but couldn't get it working properly.

The following is only a script for `parent` part which I got rid of `toggle()` for now.

```
$(function () {

    $('#mainMenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
        $('#mainMenu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        if ($(this).text() == "1st click") {
            $('#subMenu > ul').siblings().hide();
            $('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(1)').show();
        } else if ($(this).text() == "2nd click") {
            $('#subMenu > ul').siblings().hide();
            $('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(2)').show();
        }
    });
});
```

The Full code that isolates the problem is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sungsoonz/duqQN/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it. Enjoy :) Example: http://jsfiddle.net/duqQN/4/

```
$('#mainMenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
    var position = $(this).parent().index() + 1;
    $('#mainMenu li a').not($(this)).parents('li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').toggleClass('active');
    if ($(this).parents('li').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#subMenu > ul').hide();
        $('#subMenu > ul:nth-child('+position+')').show();
    } else {
        $('#subMenu > ul').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i modified the fiddle like that:

```
$(function () {

    $('#mainMenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
        $('#mainMenu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        if ($(this).text() == "1st click") {
            if($('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(1)').hasClass('active')){
                $('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(1)').hide();
                $('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(1)').removeClass('active');
            }
            else{$('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(1)').show();
                 $('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(1)').addClass('active');
            }
        } else if ($(this).text() == "2nd click") {
            if($('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(2)').hasClass('active')){
                $('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(2)').hide();
                $('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(2)').removeClass('active');
            }
            else{$('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(2)').show();
                 $('#subMenu > ul:nth-child(2)').addClass('active');
            }
        }
    });


    $('#subMenu > ul > li > a').click(function () {
        $('#subMenu li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
        }
        if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#subMenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
        }
        if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

I just used one more if/else in 
*if ($(this).text() == "1st click")* 
and *if ($(this).text() == "2st click")*.

I hope this is what you wanted. But I think there are better ways with less code to realize that.

Comment: Thanks for your input but this isn't what I was after. This code stacks up the child menu items and doesn't switch properly. My code did fine with switching over child menu, I wanted to add toggle when clicked on the same parent menu item.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could possibly help you out: (toggles between show +More or +Less)

$("#lnkMore").click(function() {

$("#divMore").slideToggle("slow");
$(this).text($(this).text() == $("#hidLess").text() ? $("#hidMore").text():$("#hidLess").text());
        return false; 
    });

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after a while messing with your really messy code, I got it.

Made `checkElement` a global variable (defined it outside of functions, so the value stored in it can be reused in other functions) and checked if it existed.

```
     if(undefined != checkElement ){
            checkElement.slideUp('normal');
    }
```

The code is really messy and shouldn't be as specific as it is, whenever I have some time I'll go back to it and try to make it simpler. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/duqQN/7/

For the 'active' check just made a general look up for 'li.active' and removed if found.

**EDIT:** Here's the code mixed with [Stuart Kershaw's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19437627/1457300) code: http://jsfiddle.net/duqQN/9/

Hope this helps!

Comment: @SeongLee Just noticed my answer wasn't what you were looking for, sorry. Mixed the code with Stuart Kershaw's so it's even better though :D